# React error loading Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a React project that uses Webpack and I have installed Bootstrap as an npm package. My issue is that, when I refresh the page in Chrome there an obvious difference to when not loading any Bootstrap CSS, however it still isn't rendering 100% properly.

My `webpack.config.js` module loaders section is as follows:

```
   'use strict'

    const path = require('path')
    const webpack = require('webpack')

    module.exports = {
      entry: [
        './browser/index'
      ],
      output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/public/js/'
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
      ],
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ]
            },
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'browser')
          },
          { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
          {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
          {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
          {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
          {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
        ]
      }
    }
```

My entry point to my React project is `index.js`

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react'
import { Route, Router, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

// Pages
import Main from './pages/main/main'
import Home from './pages/home/home'
import About from './pages/about/about'
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

render((
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route name='home' path='/' component={Main}>
   <IndexRoute component={Home} />
   <Route name='about' path='about' component={About} />
  </Route>
 </Router>), document.getElementById('app'))
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing one or two packages, or whether I need more in the Webpack file?

Comment: when you look at the css in dev tools are styles possibly being overridden or something? if you don't have any errors and can see some bootstrap styles being applied then the loaders should be fine

Comment: When I load the page with some basic Bootstrap classes within a div, such as Jumbotron, it does change the styling of the component, however it doesn't look like the Bootstrap examples. I don't have any other styles as of yet within the React app, so I don't think there are any overriding styles

Comment: Can you post some code as to how you're using it and what it looks like?

Comment: I just realised that my code included numerous `<div class='jumbotron'>` instead of className. My project works correctly now. Such a rookie mistake, apologies.

Comment: No problem. Had a feeling that's what it was

Comment: I've run into an error with Bootstrap's jQuery with the error being 'Bootstrap's Javascript requires jQuery'. I have added `window.jQuery = require('jquery')` to my entry file. Also I have added     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),

This is placed inside my Webpack.config.js. I'm sure that, yet again it's a simple mistake but I'd appreciate some expert advice